# How to setup SSH connection with Ansible?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am brand new to learning Ansible.  Here is a pretty easy example.

I have computer A, where I will be running playbooks from.

And 10 other host machines that need to be configured.  My question is, do I just need to put the public SSH key of my host machine on the 10 hosts in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ?

I guess my understanding of how to efficiently setup SSH connections between my main computer and all the clients is a little fuzzy.  Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: step one is to setup ssh keys period ... confirm you can ssh from box A onto your remote boxes ... then worry about ansible

Answer (score 3):

You create a file called hosts with this content

```
[test-vms]
10.0.0.100 ansible_ssh_pass='password' ansible_ssh_user='username'
```

In above hosts file leave off `ansible_ssh_pass='password'` if using ssh keys ... Then you can create a playbook with the commands and call the playbook like below.  The first line of the playbook needs to have the hosts declaration

```
---
- hosts: test-vms

  tasks:
  -name: "This is a test task"
   command: /bin/hostname
```

Finally, you call the playbook like this

```
ansible-playbook -i <hosts-file> <playbook.yaml>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ansible simply uses SSH so you can either copy the public key as you describe or use password authentication using the `--user` and `--ask-pass` flags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As far as connection to hosts go, Ansible sets up SSH connection between the master machine and the host machines. You have to add the SSH fingerprints to the end machines. You can always skip the *Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])* step i.e., adding the fingerprints to .ssh/known_hosts by setting host_key_checking=false

I found this great video for initial Ansible Setup - https://youtu.be/-Q4T9wLsvOQ - maybe this can help!